# Datatrigger comparison of two column values

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger, ivalueconverter

I am trying to set a `DataTrigger` based on the comparison values of two cells in the same row. My difficulty is the cells are not (and cannot be) properties of the same item. The grid is generated in code-behind.

```
public class EqualityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string currentValue = values.ToString();
        string compareToValue = Column[2].Item.Value.ToString(); //This clearly doesn't work, but it's the intent I'm after.

        if (currentValue.Equals(compareToValue))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

XAML
`(Binding Path=Value)` works great. 
`(ConverterParameter = Column2.Value)` is where my problem is.
Any suggestions how I can retrieve this???

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource EqualityConverter}}" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
</DataTrigger>
```

The reason I cannot bind to the item property is the cell value is an item by itself: So I am trying to compare to the "Value" property of Column2.

```
public class GenericProperty : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public GenericProperty(string name, object value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
```

Comment: have u seen the answer

Comment: Hey Anjum, sorry for my delay in giving a response. First thanks so much for your help. I have seen it although my first attempt was unsuccessful. BUT- I am unfamiliar with this Loaded event until now and want to give it at least one more fresh take. Will follow up shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much effort to find a simpler, more direct solution... I ended up adding a property to my object to use as a placeholder to identify matching values:

```
        public GenericProperty(string name, object value, string match)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
   **   Match = match; **
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string Match { get; set; }
```

I then have a method that loops through my Collection and sets value of my new property to "true" for items that match my "column 2" item:

```
        private void IdentifyMatchingItems(ObservableCollection<GenericObject> groupedCollection)
    {
        foreach (var collectionObject in groupedCollection)
        {
            int x = collectionObject.Properties.Count;
            int propertyCount = x - 1;
            string masterValue = collectionObject.Properties[2].Value.ToString();
            //           string ObjectNotNull = collectionObject.Properties[propertyNumber].Value.ToString();

            for (int i = 2; i <= propertyCount; i++)
            {
                if (collectionObject.Properties[i].Value.Equals(masterValue))
                {
                    collectionObject.Properties[i].Latest = "yes";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, I have a datatrigger that styles my dataGrid cell based on the "Match" property.

Answer (score 1):

`DataContext` of every `DataGridCell` is the record (item) displayed in that `DataGridRow` . So, all you have to do is just compare the value of property displayed in your second `Column`.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding secondColumnProp}" value="True">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

***UPDATE#1 after user comments***

You have to use `Loaded` event of `DataGridCell`, because by that time bindings would be evaluated.

```
   <DataGrid.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
          <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="DataGridCell_Loaded"/>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.CellStyle>

    void DataGridCell_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        DependencyObject reference = cell;
        while (reference.GetType() != typeof(DataGridRow))
            reference = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(reference);

        DataGridRow row = reference as DataGridRow;

        while (reference.GetType() != typeof(DataGrid))
            reference = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(reference);

        DataGrid grid = reference as DataGrid;
        FrameworkElement elem = grid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row);

        // use elem.DataContext, or traverse elem's visualtree to do something
        // code below is just an example
        if (elem is TextBlock)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((elem as TextBlock).Text);
            if ((elem as TextBlock).Text == "34")
                cell.Background = Brushes.DarkMagenta;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But therein lies my issue. The grid is dynamically generated and the DataGridRow is not a single record(item). I have bindings setup for all the dynamically generated columns... but I need to compare the equality of each of them to column[2]. I will edit my question to clarify.

Comment: Anjum, thanks for the solution above. In a typical scenario I believe your answer to be the best. After much attempts I wasn't able to use Cellstyle, I believe because of how Im building the dataGrid manually and assigning datatemplates from code-behind.